# PowerShell pipeline parameter binding order

Tags: powershell, parameters, typing

I have an advanced function that can accept two kinds of pipeline data:

- A custom object with a PSTypeName of "MyType"
- Any object with an ID property

Here's my function:

```
function Test-PowerShell {
    [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName = "ID")]
    param (
        [Parameter(
            Mandatory = $true,
            ParameterSetName = "InputObject",
            ValueFromPipeline = $true
        )]
        [PSTypeName('MyType')]
        $InputObject,

        [Parameter(
            Mandatory = $true,
            ParameterSetName = 'ID',
            ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true
            )]
        [int]
        $ID
    )

    process {
        if ($InputObject) {
            $objects = $InputObject
            Write-Verbose 'InputObject binding'
        }
        else {
            $objects = Get-MyType -ID $ID
            Write-Verbose 'ID binding'
        }

        # Do something with $objects
    }
}
```

I can use this function like this:

```
$obj = [PSCustomObject]@{
    PSTypeName = 'MyType'
    ID = 5
    Name = 'Bob'
}
$obj | Test-PowerShell -Verbose
```

Note that this object satisfies both of the above conditions: It is a MyType, and it has an ID property. In this case, PowerShell always binds to the ID property. This isn't ideal performance-wise because the piped object is discarded and I have to re-query it using the ID. My question is this:

**How do I force PowerShell to bind the pipeline to $InputObject if possible?**

If I change the default parameter set to InputObject, PowerShell binds on $InputObject. I don't want this, however, because when run without parameters, I want PowerShell to prompt for an ID, not an InputObject.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple answer: remove the `Mandatory` argument to the `Parameter` attribute on `$InputObject` to get the functionality you want.  I don't have enough knowledge on how parameter binding works to explain *why* this works.

```
function Test-PowerShell {
    [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName = 'ID')]
    param(
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'InputObject', ValueFromPipeline)]
        [PSTypeName('MyType')]
        $InputObject,

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'ID', Mandatory, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName)]
        [int]
        $ID
    )

    process {
        $PSBoundParameters
    }
}

$o = [pscustomobject]@{
    PSTypeName = 'MyType'
    ID         = 6
    Name       = 'Bob'
}


PS> $o | Test-PowerShell

Key         Value
---         -----
InputObject MyType


PS> [pscustomobject]@{ID = 6} | Test-PowerShell

Key Value
--- -----
ID      6
```

---

### Thoughts and experimentation below.

<s>Here's *a* workaround to your problem (defining your own type):</s>

```
Add-Type -TypeDefinition @'
public class MyType
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
'@
```

<s>And then you would tag your parameter as `[MyType]`, creating objects like you would from `[pscustomobject]`:</s>

```
[MyType]@{ ID = 6; Name = 'Bob' }
```

---

In hindsight, this method does not work.  What you're running into is the behavior of the `DefaultParameterSet`.  I'd suggest changing what you take as pipeline input.  Is there a use-case for taking the ID as pipeline input versus a user just using `Test-PowerShell -ID 5` or `Test-PowerShell` and being prompted for the ID?

Here's a suggestion that may work as you intend from my testing:

```
function Test-PowerShell {
    [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName = 'ID')]
    param(
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'InputObject', Mandatory = $true, ValueFromPipeline = $true)]
        [PSTypeName('MyType')]
        $InputObject,

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'ID', Mandatory = $true, ValueFromPipeline = $true)]
        [int]
        $ID
    )

    process {
        $PSBoundParameters
    }
}
```

---

To take an example from an existing built-in cmdlet, they don't use the same name or properties on an object for multiple parameters.  In `Get-ChildItem`, both the `LiteralPath` and `Path` take pipeline input, but `LiteralPath` only takes it by PropertyName `LiteralPath` or `PSPath` (aliased).  `Path` is ByValue and PropertyName, but only as `Path`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. From what I can tell, the main difference in your code is a custom type definition instead of using PSTypeName?

Comment: @DavidHaymond Yes, but that doesn't actually make a difference so you can ignore it.  I go further with my thought in my edit; try refreshing.

Comment: That's not quite what I'm looking for. To use another built-in cmdlet example, `InputObject` accepts pipeline input ByValue only, and `Id` accepts pipeline ByPropertyName only. When I run `Stop-Process` without parameters, it prompts for `Id`, so it would appear that the ID parameter set is default. When passed a process object (e.g. `Get-Process | Stop-Process`), how does PowerShell know to bind it to `InputObject` instead of `Id`, since the process object has an `Id` property?

Comment: @DavidHaymond So I found a way to make it work like the `Stop-Process` cmdlet: **remove** `Mandatory` from the `Parameter` attribute for `$InputObject`

Comment: Thank you; that worked! I think it must be because PowerShell uses the specified arguments (and not the pipeline) to determine which parameter set to select. If `InputObject` and `ID` are both mandatory, PowerShell can't determine the appropriate parameter set to use regardless of the pipeline value, so it selects the default parameter set and _then_ binds the pipeline input. If `InputObject` isn't mandatory, the `InputObject` parameter set is valid and is selected by PowerShell, and the pipeline is bound to `InputObject`.

Comment: @DavidHaymond the only thing is `Stop-Process` manages to have both mandatory so there might be a way to get that done in C#

Comment: Yeah, probably. I think I'm going to write my next module in C#.

Comment: To understand how `Stop-Process` is set up, install `MetaProgramming` from the gallery and run `New-ProxyCommand Stop-Process`. Nothing jumps out at me except the order in which they are defined (`InputObject` is mandatory). `ValueFromPipeline` takes precedence over `ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName`, FWIW.